# Variadic template not printing the last parameter

Tags: c++, variadic-templates

I'm trying to write a simple logger using variadic templates for my understanding. It works, but with a catch.

```
void log() {
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
// variadic Template
template<class T, class... Args>                
void log(T t1, Args... args) {          
    std::cout << t1<<" ";
    log(args...);
}

int main()
{
    log("Logging", 1, 2, 3.2, 4);
    return 0;
}
```

This is not outputting the last parameter `'4'` in the console. The output for this is

`Logging 1 2 3.2`

When I debugged, it's not entering the 'empty' log function at all. In fact, it compiles and gives the same output without that empty `log()` function.

Can someone please explain why this is behaving that way?

Comment: Works fine here: https://onlinegdb.com/BJjpSEAYz

Comment: Same thing happens to my in Visual Studio 2017, only prints 3.2

Comment: @DarkFalcon Interesting.. I am using Visual Studio 2017 and can't get this output at all. I rebuilt and changed parameters etc., printing the new output but always skipping the last parameter and newline character.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that Visual C++ pulls in [`std::log`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/log) into the global namespace.

Your chain of calls **should** be

```
log("Logging", 1, 2, 3.2, 4);
log(1, 2, 3.2, 4);
log(2, 3.2, 4);
log(3.2, 4);
log(4);
log();
```

The problem with Visual C++ is that the next to last call, `log(4)`, is really `std::log(4)`, which of course will not call your own `log` function.

The simplest solution is to rename your function as something else.

Comment: If log(4); doesn't call his templated log function, how does it call the non-templated one above it if it doesn't take any arguments?

Comment: Do you mean that that name (`log`) is already "dumped" into the global namespace?

Comment: @Zebrafish Non-template function is always preferable during overload resolution.

Comment: @考えネロク Yes. It seems like some system header file includes `<math.h>` instead of `<cmath>`.

Comment: Spot on! Had I passed a string as the last parameter, it works as expected.

Comment: @Zebrafish `log(4)` calls neither OP's `log` function template nor OP's `log` non-template function, but `std::log` which was dumped into the global namespace.

Comment: @SaileshD, passing std::string as the last parameter is kinda hacking not a solution, it works only because, std::log is not overloaded with this type. Debugging each step will help you find a key to the possible solution and the root of the problem.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, it definitely includes `<cmath>`

Comment: @SmitYcyken of course.. I am not suggesting that this is the right way as long as the parameters are fine.. Just saying that I wouldn't have found this problem if I had passed a string.

Comment: @SaileshD, and now i suppose you know why =)

Comment: @考えネロク I realise that... now.

Answer (score 4):

In Visual Studio is it better to use namespace for similar with std function names

In global namespace call of `log(4)` evaluates to  macro `_GENERIC_MATH1(log, _CRTDEFAULT)` defined in `xtgmath.h`

[image]

```
#include <iostream> // - this indirectly includes macro _GENERIC_MATH1 from ^^^^^^^
namespace mylog{

    void log() {}

    // variadic Template
    template<class T, class... Args>
    void log(T t1, Args... args) 
    {
        std::cout << t1 << " ";
        log(args...); // calling log with parameter pack
        // but the last call is log(4)
        // which is calling macro _GENERIC_MATH1 in global namespace
    }
}

int main()
{
    mylog::log("Logging", 1, 2, 3.2, 4);
    return 0;
}
```

For additional information have a look at the [Some programmer dude](https://stackoverflow.com/users/440558/some-programmer-dude) answer.